# Ошибка в моем сервере на Python

Tags: python, сокет, windows-10, pygame, python-3.8

Я пишу игру на Python 3.8 с изпользованием библиотеки Pygame.
Писал сервер с использованием библиотек socket и threading
Хотя айпи и порт указан правильно, сервер не хочет запускатся, выдаёт ошибку [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied. У меня есть переменная self.conencted, которая обозначает, запустился ли сервер.
Она почему-то ставится на true
Вот код моего класса:

```
class Server(Thread):
    def __init__(self, name, identifier, ip, port):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port

        Thread.__init__(self)

        self.name = name
        self.id = identifier
        self.connected = False
        self.tosend = None
        self.data = None
        self.conn = None
        self.addr = None
        self.alive = True

        self.s = socket.socket()
        self.s.setblocking(False)

    def connect(self):
        timer = 0
        starttimer = time.perf_counter()
        self.connected = False
        while timer < 5:
            try:
                self.s.bind((self.ip, self.port))
                self.connected = True
                print('LOG: Started server!')
            except socket.error as e:
                print('LOG: ERROR:', e)

            timer = time.perf_counter() - starttimer

    def getdata(self):
        toreturn = self.data
        self.data = None
        return toreturn

    def isConnected(self):
        return self.connected

    def send(self, data):
        self.tosend = data

    def setAlive(self, b):
        self.alive = b

    def getAlive(self):
        return self.alive

    def run(self):
        print('LOG: Binding server...')
        self.connect()
        if self.connected:
            self.s.listen(1)
            while self.alive:
                try:
                    self.conn, self.addr = self.s.accept()
                    print("LOG: NEW CONNECTION:", self.conn, self.addr)
                    break
                except socket.error:
                    pass

            while self.alive:
                try:
                    self.data = self.conn.recv(16384).decode('utf-8')
                except socket.error:
                    pass

                try:
                    if self.tosend is not None:
                        self.conn.send(self.tosend.encode('utf-8'))
                        self.tosend = None
                except socket.error:
                    pass
```

Если нужны дополнительные файлы, [вот мой репозиторий на GitHub](https://github.com/3elDU/BattleKiller/tree/testing)
Прошу помочь, хотел сделать свою игру, все получалось, но тут этот баг, целый день просидел, ничего не могу понять.

Comment: В какой строке ошибка-то?

Comment: self.s.bind((self.ip, self.port)) в функции connect

Comment: если мне память не изменяет, pygame старше Python 3.65 не умеет ))

Comment: @VasylKolomiets попробую установить 3.65, но у меня с 3.8 все прекрасно работает